# debug python versions < 3.5 with vscode new debugger

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

In recent vscode versions, the Python extension now uses debugpy as the default python debugger, replacing the old ptvsd.

I need to debug a python script in a software program that works with python 3.2 and not with newer versions. Unfortunately, debugpy works only with python > 3.4.

Is there a way to use another debugger, or to choose which debugger to use, in vscode python extension?
In other terms, is it possible to debug python < 3.5 scripts in vscode?

Comment: just debug the program with python 3.8 and don't use language features not available in python 3.2

Comment: The problem is the software using the script uses python 3.2 and cannot use a different python version. So no, i cannot debug the script with python 3.8

Comment: then install an old version of the extension

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need to downgrade the version of Python used by VSCode. In the extensions find Python and install another version.

[image]